# What is difference between Noise Filters (Savitzki Golay) and Interpolation(interp1d) Python

Tags: python, pandas, filter, scipy, interpolation

I am wondering what is difference between filtering and interpolating data.

I am now comparing

```
savgol_filter(itp(xx), window_size, poly_order)
```

and

```
itp = interp1d(x,y, kind='nearest')
```

I understand that filter filters noise in data, so that they are more smooth.
But the same does the interpolating.

My purpose is to smooth data, so that data will be ever rising.
If they are not ever rising then adjust only those values that break it.
And if there are rising = NO ADJUSTMENT.
What would you recommend to use?
Thanks!

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could include a representative sample of your data. I am not sure the `savgol_filter` is adapted to what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a series of discrete data points, measured for example at specific time.

- Interpolation is a way to guess the value of the series at a time in-between two measurements. For example, the temperature is measured every hours, but you want to have the temperature value every half-hour. If the data is noisy, the interpolation will be noisy too.
- Filtering is a way to reduce the noise in the data. The value given by the measurement is the real value plus a random noise. For multiple measurements, the real value is assumed to remain identical, while the noise value will change positively and negatively. Therefore, by taking the average over enough multiple measurements the contribution of the noise averaged to zero.

Fitting a model over the data is another similar way to remove the noise from the data. Actually, taking the average is similar to fit the data using a straight horizontal line as a model. Doing a linear regression is fitting with any line i.e. finding the straight line which best describes the data.

The Savitzky–Golay filter performs successive fits over successive parts of the data series (window) in order to reduce locally the noise.